Circular Dependency when Creating Safari Extension App
I am following these instructions to created a Safari Web Extension App project:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/creating_a_safari_web_extension
When I try to compile the default code, I get this error:
Circular dependency between modules 'Dispatch' and 'Foundation'

At one point, it showed the error was in generatedassetssymbols.swift file, although I cant replicate that now.
macOS, Sonoma 14.0, xcode 15.4
Update: If I try on another machine with Ventura (13.5.2) everything works as expected.
Anyone know what is going on? It is literally the default project without any changes.

